# React Native Flatlist Debugging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

For my app I need an "addRecipe" component that renders a dynamic number of input fields, which each represent the steps in a recipe. By default there is one step, but more can be added by pressing on the "add" button. I want to render the steps as RecipeStep components using a FlatList, but I get the following error in the devtools debugger:

```
 try {
    // This should throw.
    if (construct) {
      // Something should be setting the props in the constructor.
      var Fake = function Fake() {
        throw Error();
      }; // $FlowFixMe
```

Im having trouble identifying the issue.

The following is the code for my addRecipe component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput,FlatList, Button, ScrollView, InputAccessoryView} from 'react-native'
import RecipeStep from '../components/recipeStep.js';
import {auth} from '../firebase.js'

export default function AddRecipe({navigation}){
    const [steps, setSteps] = useState([{description: '', duration: '', key: 0}]);

    var stepNumber = 1;
    const addHandler = ()=>{
        const _steps = [...steps];
        _steps.push({key: stepNumber, value: '', duration:''});
        setSteps(_steps); 
        stepNumber += 1;
    }


    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Add a recipe here!</Text>
            <Text>{steps[0].key}</Text>
            <ScrollView>
                <FlatList
                    data={steps}
                    renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
                    <RecipeStep item={item}/>
                    )}
                />
            </ScrollView>
            <Button title="Add" onPress={addHandler} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

I'm loosely basing this code off of this tutorial, which does in fact work as its own project when I run it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH_SoXiu_Hk&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ixPU-QkScoRBVxtPPzVjrQ&index=11

I know that the RecipeStep component is not the issue, because I get the same error when I replace it with a  component.

Comment: I ended up using array.map to render the components instead of the FlatList

Answer (score 0):

you are adding object to a constant,
replace const _steps = [...steps];
with let _steps = [...steps];

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, but the flatlist still does not render and I get the same error